# pgfplot: use pgfmathdeclarefunction defined function within coordinate

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

This code snippet defines a simple function using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` (e.g. `f()`) and `\pgfmathparse`. I would like to use the defined function `f()` within other coordinate, e.g. `(0.2, f(0.2))` vs. `(0.2, f(0.2)`. Note the latter has one fewer `)`. Both usage do plot the dot, but the former results pgfplots error:

> error| Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, I could not read the plot coordinates near ')'

I would like to know are these usage of defined function `f()` correct?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
  }
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1,]
    % this draw the plot, but also report an error
    \addplot[mark=*, blue] coordinates {(0.2, f(0.2))};
    % this works
    \addplot[mark=*, blue] coordinates {(0.2, f(0.2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the function is used inside a coordinate pair, then you get two closing parentheses:

```
(0.2, f(0.2))
```

This apparently confuses the parser. These parentheses are not matched like
curly braces in \TeX, when an argument is read. A set of curly braces protects the
inner parentheses:

```
(0.2, {f(0.2)})
```

Then the inner delimiters are hidden for the parser that looks for the
closing coordinate pair delimiter.