# Flamm's paraboloid graph

Tags: 3d

How to  draw  [Flamm's paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) ?

tikz,pstricks,metapost,asymptote

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,width=8cm}

\begin{document}

The spatial curvature of the Schwarzschild solution for $r > r_s$ .....

$w=2\sqrt{r_s(r-r_w)}$

For this exemple: w=z, r_s=y and r=x.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3{2*sqrt(y*(x-y))}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505833/how-to-draw-a-black-hole-near-horizon-geometry-in-tikz and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505844/how-to-display-a-duck-or-marmot-swallowed-by-a-darkhole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the surface, the Flamm's paraboloid, but I'd think of something like this, assuming that the equation is using cylindrical polar coordinates:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,width=8cm}

\begin{document}
The spatial curvature of the Schwarzschild solution for $r>r_s\ldots$
\[w=2\sqrt{r_s(r-r_s)}.\]

For this example: $w=z$ and $r_s=1$.
\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[surf,domain=1:10,domain y=0:2*pi,samples=31] ({\x*cos(\y r)},{\x*sin(\y r)},{2*sqrt(\x-1)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flamm's paraboloid.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you@Juan, @samcarter. Is it possible to have the same image orientation, color, large horizon. I'll try with view and colormap.